# how to call an Oracle function from PHP that returns more than 1,000,000 buffer (max)

Tags: php, plsql

My oracle is not paid. So I can not use unlimited buffer size. my php code is as below:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('****', '****', '****');
if($conn){
    $operation = isset($_POST['****']) ? $_POST['****'] : NULL;
    $year = isset($_POST['****']) ? $_POST['****'] : NULL;
    $month = isset($_POST['****']) ? $_POST['****'] : NULL;

    switch($operation){
        case 'summary':
            $sql = "BEGIN
                    :RET:=RKARIM.PKG_SR_FUNCTIONS.REPORT_NET(:SAL_YEAR_MONTH);
                    END;";
            $parse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
            oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":RET", $ret, 32767);
            oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":SAL_YEAR_MONTH", $sal_year_month);
            oci_execute($parse);
            echo htmlentities($ret);
            break;
        case 'allowances':
                NULL;
            break;
        case 'deductions':
                NULL;
            break;
    }

    oci_close($conn);
    unset($_POST['****']);
    unset($_POST['****']);  
    unset($_POST['****']);
}
else{
    echo 'Server down.';
    die;
    }
?>
```

Now `REPORT_NET(SAL_YEAR_MONTH NUMBER)` function from oracle returns a huge string (more than max buffer). First it was an XMLTYPE. But its a problem to handle XMLTYPE in PHP so I changed it in VARCHAR2. But as its a huge string how do I get it? If I run this script then my oracle function shows me this error:

```
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want CLOB? Or maybe (depending on what it does, exactly), you need to refactor RKARIM.PKG_SR_FUNCTIONS.REPORT_NET to return a ref cursor instead of a large string? I'm thinking that maybe it's doing some sort of concatenation to get the results into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see that you have limited your return to 32767 characters. I would change that to clob (as already has been suggested). Something like:

```
$ret = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($parse,':RET', $ret, OCI_B_CLOB);
```